# Lucene query with range

Tags: java, lucene

I'm indexing some items which include `title` and `cost` as fields. Cost is a double value.
I'm preparing a query such as:

```
(title:item~0.8) AND (cost:[0.0 TO 200.0])
```

After parsing, `query.toString()` looks like this:

```
+title:item~0 +cost:[0.0 TO 200.0]
```

**From the results returned, it is obvious that `cost` is not considered.**
I know for sure that `cost` is indexed because I can retrieve it.
Indexing code:

```
public void index(Set<Item> items) throws IOException {
    String path = "D:\\lucenedata\\myproj";
    Directory fsDir = FSDirectory.open(new File(path));
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    IndexWriterConfig iwConf = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_10_3, analyzer);
    iwConf.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE);
    IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(fsDir, iwConf);
    for (Item item : items) {
        Document d = new Document();
        if (item.getCost() != null) {
            d.add(new DoubleField("cost", item.getCost().doubleValue(), Store.YES));
        }
        d.add(new TextField("title", item.getTitle(), Store.YES));
        indexWriter.addDocument(d);
    }
    indexWriter.commit();
    indexWriter.close();
    System.out.println("Indexed " + items.size() + " items");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up subclassing `QueryParser` and then creating a `NumericRange` when `cost` is encountered. It works well.

```
public class WebSearchQueryParser extends QueryParser {

    public WebSearchQueryParser(String f, Analyzer a) {
        super(f, a);
    }

    protected Query getRangeQuery(final String field, final String min, final String max,
            final boolean startInclusive, final boolean endInclusive) throws ParseException {
        if ("cost".equals(field)) {
            return NumericRangeQuery.newDoubleRange(field, Double.parseDouble(min), Double.parseDouble(max),
                    startInclusive, endInclusive);
        }
        return super.getRangeQuery(field, min, max, startInclusive, endInclusive);
    }
}
```

And then initialize:

```
QueryParser queryParser = new WebSearchQueryParser("title", new StandardAnalyzer());
```

and parse my query as before `(title:item~0.8) AND (cost:[0.0 TO 200.0])`

Answer (score 1):

`QueryParser` does not generate numeric range queries.  So you are searching for values where cost is between 0.0 and 200.0 lexicographically, rather than numerically.  Furthermore, numeric fields are translated to a prefix coded form in the index, so your results will be pretty unpredictable.

It's better to generate your numeric ranges through the Query API, using [`NumericRangeQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html), instead of the QueryParser, and them combine them with your parsed query using a [`BooleanQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html).  Something like:

```java
Query parsedQuery = parser.parse(title:item~0.8);
Query costQuery = NumericRangeQuery.newDoubleRange("cost", 0.00, 200.0, true, true);
BooleanQuery finalQuery = new BooleanQuery();
finalQuery.add(new BooleanClause(parsedQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
finalQuery.add(new BooleanClause(costQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
```

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation. I also found that combining that way doesn't work. Instead I wrote a custom QueryParser which creates new NumericRange if "cost" column is encountered. I will post my solution also.